# How can i load website's summary contents faster?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, xml

I have a method on MasterPage of my website and it loads the summary contents of my Website like Last News, Last Posts, Most visited Posts and etc. all data have been load from SQL database tables. this method call per user visit (over 40000 time a day) and So i have 40000 unnecessary connection to database a day because theses data usually change maximum 4 or 5 time a day.

My question is: What is the solution to optimize page load speed and connect to database only on changes.

I have a solution but i am not sure about that. only on data changes i can connect to database and get a Dataset of contents and write it to an XML file, then read the XML file from my MasterPage.

Please tell me the best solution and your opinion about my solution.

Thank you

Comment: How urgent is it that you see the new data? If you don't mind data being stale for (say) 2 minutes, then just put a cache in... I suspect you'll find that easier to implement than change detection.

Comment: No. it is not urgent. How can i cache?

Comment: Well that's a very broad question - I suggest you do some research on it...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem with your solution. The only thing I would add is to have the page:

1. Read the xml file if it exists
2. Delete the file after read
3. Use ASP.Net Caching to cache the contents of the file

Now, the MasterPage will first check for existance of the file, if the file exists it indicates the data has changed and the cache needs to be updated. If the file does not exist, the data in the cache is the freshest we have and can be used.

Pulling data from the cache (Server RAM) is really fast, faster than reading in the file (File IO), which is much faster than connecting to the Db and getting the data from there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how exactly you detect that your data change, in my case I have a `DataTable` stored in [Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and when the user add or modify a record, I set `null` my `DataTable` variable and when I call it if fill itself again, also it will be deleted every 5 minutes because of `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5d)`

```
DataTable dtJobs
{
    get { if (Cache["dtJobs"] == null) Cache["dtJobs"] = Provider.Job.getAll(); return (DataTable)Cache["dtJobs"]; }
    set { if (value != null) Cache.Insert("dtJobs", value, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5d), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
          else Cache.Remove("dtJobs");
    }
}
```